# Detecting a photograph (i.e. rectangle) on screen using find contours?

Tags: c++, opencv, find

I'm trying to detect a photograph in front of the screen with OpenCV (using a webcam). I am using the following code, which uses findContours() to detect rectangles (which for my purpose would count as a photograph.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp

This works well, but findContours expects a white background against black, so the image needs to be inverted. I tried changing the threshold, but i still can't get it to detect a photograph.

Am i going about this the right way or would there be a better approach to this.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you upload sample input image and the piece of code that you have written ?

Comment: The code i used is quoted earlier and the image is just a regular sized photograph.

Comment: Ok, but it would be better if you upload the sample input image as well, it would help to solve the problem effictively. Thanks